# How to calculate the Cyclic redundancy check [CRC] given an input sequence?

Tags: coding-theory, binary

In digital communications a **Cyclic Redundancy Check** [CRC] is an error detecting code that are used to protect a number of given bits similar to concept of parity bit.

I have included a diagram of block diagram that aims to calculate the CRC specific to input bits $m_0 m_1\cdots m_{33}$.
[image]

In the book that I have been using the following sentence and example are provided

> *Bits are then passed sequentially through the exclusive-or operation (`XOR`) at the input. When the last bit has entered, the output is generated by shifting the bits out of the shift register, `c7` first, through an inverter* 
> *As an example,
>
> If bits $\{m_0 \ldots m_{33}\}$ are given by $\{1111000100100110000000001110000000\}$, the resulting CRC bits `{c7. . .c0}` are `{10101000}`*.

Can anyone please explain to be how they mathematically obtain the 8 bits?

i. e. what are the actual operations, because I can't tell much from the figure itself.

Comment: See section 2.3.4, pages 61-64 (equation 2.18), in this _Data Networks_ book: http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Data_Link_Data_Nets.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Michael